# NodeJS event loop wrong order

Tags: node.js, express, event-loop

My express code:

```
app.use('/test', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout')); // setTimeout (macrotask)
    User.findOne().then(user => console.log('user')); // promise (microtask)
    console.log('console.log');
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

The console output order is:

```
console.log
setTimeout
user
```

**Question: Why microtask is executed after macrotask?**

For example, in the browser the next code resolves in correct order:

Code:

```
setTimeout(function timeout() {
  console.log(3);
}, 0);

let p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {}
  resolve();
});

p.then(function () {
  console.log(2);
});

console.log(1);
```

Order:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Check this https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The micro-task needs to be queued before the macro-task has been dequeued off the macro-task queue for it to run first. Since `.findOne()` takes some time, the micro-task isn't queued until the promise returned by `.findOne()` resolves, which happens after your `setTimeout` callback has been added to the macro-task queue, and then dequeue onto the call stack and executed.

Your "working" code is different to your situation in your Node program with `.findOne()`, since the executor function for the Promise you're creating runs synchronously (in fact you'll see that this code produces 1, 2, 3 in Node as well):

```
setTimeout(function timeout() { // <--- queue `timeout` callback as a macro-task
  console.log(3);
}, 0);

let p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { // run this function synchronously
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {} // <--- wait here for the loop to complete
  resolve();
});
// Only reached once the loop above has complete, as thus, your promise has resolved 
p.then(function () { // <--- `p` has resolved, so we queue the function as a micro-task
  console.log(2);
});

console.log(1); // <--- add the function to call stack (first log to execute)
```

Above, while we're executing the script, both the setTimeout callback and the .then() callback are added to their respective task-queues so that once the script has finished executing, the micro-task can be dequeued and put onto the stack, and then the macro-task can be deqeued and put onto the stack.

Your code is different:

```
/* 
setTimeout gets added to the callstack, that spins off an API which after 0 m/s adds your callback to the macro-task queue
*/
setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout')); 

/* 
.findOne() gets added to the call stack, that spins off an API which after N m/s adds the `.then()` callback to the micro-task queue (N > 0)
*/
User.findOne().then(user => console.log('user')); // promise (microtask)

/* 
While the above API is working in the background, our script can continue on...
console.log() gets added to the call stack and "console.log" gets logged
*/
console.log('console.log');
```

Once the script above has finished, the `timeout` callback is on the macro-task queue, but the `.then()` callback isn't on the micro-task queue yet, as the query is still being executed in the background. The `timeout` callback then gets dequeued onto the call stack. After some time, your `.then()` callback is added to the micro-task queue and executed once the callstack is empty it gets moved from the queue to the stack.